# c# sorting and getting the last row of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I want to sort the data in datagridview by numbers, and I want to display the specific cell of last row in a textbox. How can I do that?

my code : (EDITED)

```
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {   
            int nRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;

            dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Selected = true;

            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString() ; << exception occur
```

And i get this NullReferenceException.

How to solve this?

PS: I have 3 columns there, I need to get the 3rd columns of the last row.

Comment: just added, I forgot to include the codes that I wrote.

Comment: How many columns you have in your datagridview? It looks no of columns in your gridview is less than 4.If not then tell exactly which line of code is causing exception.

Comment: are you sure there are 4 cells from 0 to 3? try this: textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns .Count -1].Value.ToString() ;

Comment: the last line is causing the exception, I have 3 columns in the datagridview.

Comment: Oh, yes, should be textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString() , but not 3, but I get NullreferenceException.

Comment: Because you are getting last row with dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1 which means its returning correct row but problem could be with columns/cell index. you said there are 3 columns hence last column index should be 2 not 3?

Comment: yeah, I've changed, I just realized sorry, but I get another NullReferenceException, there is data inside the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exeption because you are trying to get the fourth cell (`dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[3]`) and you have, as you said, only 3 cells(columns). Just change your code to:

```
textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: yea, but I have NullReferenceException after changing into this line of code

Comment: Check if dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex] is null in debugger.

Comment: Well, I can't teach you how to use debugger. Just put a break point to that line and use QuickWatch for example. You have to know that if you want to programm anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count -1].Value.ToString() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, I have changed your code a bit:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)         
{                
    int nRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;              
    dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Selected = true;              
    if(dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[2].Value != null)
        textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString() ;          }
```

Comment: The code that you gave, the system just highlight the last row of the datagridview, but not displaying the data into the textbox.

Comment: This means that the data in the last cell of the row is null and it is the reason you were getting the error. Now try to see what is wrong there.

Comment: It's weird, the specified cell does contain numbers in it, but it can't get the data. That's why it is null.

Answer (score 0):

In page_load ()

write  :->  gvJobCard.PageIndex = Int32.MaxValue;

protected void gvJobCard_RowDataBound(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)

{

gvJobCard.PageIndex = gvJobCard.PageCount - 1;   //It works for DESC order in gvJOBCARD

}